# Using curl_easy_init in the constructor leads to segfault

Tags: c++, libcurl

When I wrap libcurl in class I face with problem:

```
Foo::Foo()
{
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl)
        throw std::runtime("Can't initialize libcurl");
}

char* Foo::GetPage(char *url)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteData );
    curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)data);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform( curl );
}
```

I got a segfault on the first line of GetPage function (setting url). If I initalize curl in the GetPage - all is OK. Anyone else faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

the variable is losing it's scope. Check the value of curl variable when it enters in GetPage function.

Comment: Thanks, I find the problem. Variable curl - is a member of class Foo, so when I use one it cause to segfault. Value of variable is correct, but it can't be put to the library.